# First kind Volterra integral equation regularity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Let $K(x,y) \in {L^2}({(0,1)^2})$ and $g \in {L^2}(0,1)$. We consider the following integral equation
$$\int\limits_0^x {K(x,t)f(t)dt = g(x)} $$
My question: what can we say about the regularity of $f$ if it exists? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing we can say without knowing more about $g$, since any $f \in L^2$ may be the solution of such an equation with a suitable $g$.

Comment: Thank you sir. What if wa add $f$ to tge second member which will make the equation of second kind. Can we ensure that $f$  is $L^2$? thank you.